# Значение выражения: "пошла на разгон"?

Tags: семантика

Правильно ли я понимаю значение выражения: "пошла на разгон" значит набирает скорость (машина)?
Употребляется ли выражение в переносном смысле, например "жизнь пошла на разгон"? Если да, что тогда оно обозначает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Жизнь пошла на разгон.***

Это **авторская метафора**, расширение значения слова (переход от материальных предметов к более отвлеченным понятиям).

РАЗОГНАТЬ 6. кого-что. Наращивая скорость движения **чего-л.,** довести её до очень большой. Р. лошадь. Р. автомобиль, мотоцикл.